# I've never seen encryption before. What does this C encryption snippet do?

Tags: c, encryption

I was given some code a few weeks ago as part of an application to an encryption job I was interested in. They sent me a code and basically wanted to see if I understood it and could improve it.

I tried my best but all the code was brand new to me and I couldn't figure out what it did. I eventually gave it up as a lost cause as I had other things to do. However, I'm still very interested in learning about it, just for knowledge sake. Can anyone help me learn more about this type of programming or what specifically this does?

I'll try to cut it down and give my impressions.

This is the part that does the actual encryption; from what I could figure out, using an XOR encryption. Is this correct? I also believe input_2 and input_1 are erroneously switched.

```
typedef int int32;
typedef char int8;

void change_it(int8 *output, int8 *input_1, const int8 *input_2, int32 length)
{
    int32 i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = (int8)(input_1[i] ^ input_2[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Here they overloaded an `itoa` to make the string into either decimal or a hex digit, although for what purpose I'm unsure.

```
void itoa( int32 num, int8  *alpha, int32 radix )
{
    if( radix == 10 )
    {
        sprintf(alpha, "%i", num);
    }
    else if( radix == 16 )
    {
        sprintf(alpha, "%X", num);
    }
}
```

This is the main running function that main calls. It does some weird bitwise stuff and then calls change_it 4 times. This was the part that mostly stumped me.

```
int8 *modify_it(int32 modifier, const int8  *input_1, int32 length)
{
    int8  leading[3];
    int32 i_leading;
    int8 * temp_string = NULL;
    int8 * ret;
    int32 i = 0;

    itoa(modifier/2, leading, 10);
    i_leading = atoi(leading);

    temp_string = (int8 *) malloc(8);
    ret = (int8 *) malloc(length);
    memset(temp_string, 0, 8);
    temp_string[0] = 0;

    if( (modifier+1)%2 == 0 ) {
        temp_string[0] = (int8)((i_leading<<4) + 8);
    }
    else {
        temp_string[0] = (int8)(i_leading<<4);
    }

    for(i=0; i<(length>>3); i++)
    {
        change_it(ret+i*8, temp_string, input_1+i*8, 8);
    }
    free(temp_string);

    return ret;
}
```

Last, but never least, the main function to start it off.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int8 data[32];
    memset(data, 0x0A, sizeof(data));

    int8 *resp = modify_it(0xFF, data, sizeof(data));

    free(resp);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What this does, basically, is - for back of a better term - obfuscate the input.

This is a very amateurish attempt by someone that will fail pretty badly at both securing and storing data.

There are many errors like clearing an array (which could've been done during the allocation with calloc) and then 'making sure' it is cleared again by clearing part of it 'manually'. There are so many, many things wrong with this it makes me want to both puke and laugh.

If this is not homework, throw it away. Do not try to learn from it. There is nothing that is correct or good about this code.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful input. What do you recommend I google to learn more about doing this the correct way?

Comment: Creating your own encryption algorithm is a difficult, difficult thing. Cryptologists learn for years about the mathematics behind the things they are doing, they design things in teams, and then their algorithms are analyzed by dozens of other cryptographers. Then it turns it they were pieces of crap and are thrown out. I don't mean to discourage you but, nowadays, there's not much to learn from source code. Instead you should google how encryption is attacked - mathematically - in addition to how it is done.

Comment: When you've learned about historical methods of encryption, and of how that encryption was broken, and follow that history, you will begin to get a much clearer picture. So, I suppose that the best place I can point you is to the history of encryption. It is a worthwhile exercise to implement things like the ancient substitution cipher and others that you come across if you're interested in learning it for yourself, just to understand them.

Answer (score 4):

There are many levels at which to critique the code.

1. It doesn't have any input or output so the functions may as well not be there.
2. When you add output, the data to be encrypted is fixed (32 newlines).
3. The 'encryption' is done with a feeble mechanism (XOR encryption done right is stronger than ROT-13, but not by much.
4. The 'key' is a single fixed byte based on the `0xFF` passed into the `modify_it()` function
   plus 7 zero bytes.
5. XOR with 0 doesn't conceal anything, so only 1 byte of each 8 is altered by the code.
6. It uses the most rudimentary [ECB](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption_modes) (electronic code book) mode, encrypting each 8-byte block independently, rather than any more complex scheme (CBC, etc).
7. The code does not demonstrate decryption.
8. The code does not demonstrate that decrypting the encrypted material leaves you with the original material.
9. It does not error check the calls such as `malloc()`.
10. There's a buffer overflow when formatting `127` into `leading`.
11. Serious cryptographic code would need to overwrite keys once it was finished with them.

Etc.

Overall, the 'ignore this code' advice is sound.  But, the company that sent it to you was probably fully aware that it is garbage.  They wanted to see what issues you would come up with, and how you'd go about analyzing it, and if you provided remedies, what remedies you'd provide.

Treat it as a simple piece of bad C code; analyze it as such.  Keep a cryptographic eye on things if you have the knowledge to do so, but there is much to criticize even without knowing much about encryption.

```
Before:
0x0000: 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
0x0010: 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
After:
0x0000: F2 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A F2 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
0x0010: F2 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A F2 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
Decrypt:
0x0000: 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
0x0010: 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A   ................
```